# difference between "^string" and "string" in varnish

Tags: varnish

Can somebody tell me what is the difference between `"^string" and "string"` in varnish when we evaluate with `~` in varnish

both does not evaluate similarly 
and one more when we add a `\` it is again different

eg

```
~ "^index.php/sting" is different to ~ "^/string"
```

am totally confused

Can somebody show me a link to a cheat sheet or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of regex, `^` means the beginning of the string, meaning

`^/string` will match `/string123` but not `/application/string`

`/string` will match both `/string123` and `/application/string`

`^string` will not match `/string` but will match `string/123` or `string123`

`string` will match all `/string`, `string`, `123string` and any thing that contains the word `string`